# change css on cron job in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have table displaying some data from a table in a ctp file. I want to know whether it is possible to change the css property of a particular row on cron job trigger.

Say the table display the Title, Description, Starttime.
When the starttime equals the current time, i want to change the background of that particular row only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you'd need a cron job for such a feature.

You can just check whether the data date is the current date and add a special class to the row. The exact technique you'd use depends on how you display the table, but using the HTML helper:

```
foreach( $data as $row ) {
    echo $this->Html->tableCells(
        array(
            array( 'Column 1', 'Column 2', '...' ) 
        ),
        ( $row[ 'date' ] == date( 'Y-m-d' ) ) ? 'highlight' : '',
        ( $row[ 'date' ] == date( 'Y-m-d' ) ) ? 'highlight' : ''
    );
}
```

In the CSS:

```
.highlight {
    background-color:yellow;
}
```